# Generating Dynamic Class Java

Tags: java, file-io, dynamic-compilation, dynamic-class

I am generating a dynamic class in my java program by writing all my code into a java file, compiling the java file into a class file and then loading the class file with a URLClassLoader.  The problem with this is that it creates a lot of files on my computer. Is their a way to do this with only creating "virtual files"(file objects) and not generating any actual files, because the way im doing it takes time and seems unclean and inefficient.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html ?

Comment: but dont i still need to create the .java file so that i can compile it

Comment: see the JavaSourceFromString example for a possible solution in @Affe 's link.

Comment: there is no particular requirement that the implementation of javax.tools.JavaFileObject represent an actual file on disk, no, it can just be a wrapper around a string in memory.  (sorry, don't mean to be obtuse, just too busy at the moment to write a full blown answer and thought maybe if we pointed you in the right direction you'd be able to find some tutorials around the web that will help you out.)

Comment: but when i load the class i need a class file to load it from

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the ClassLoader class, it has a method to define a class from the actual series of bytes.

[Java docs for ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

I admit I have not worked with class loaders on this low of a level, but my understanding is that this is a template pattern, where the base ClassLoader class knows how to create a class in the VM based off raw byte code.  Child classes are responsible for figuring out where to find the byte code for a given class.

So the solution for you may be to stop using URLClassLoader entirely and extend ClassLoader yourself.

Comment: that seems a bit complicated

Answer (score 1):

Byte code generation and manipulation libraries allow you to modify and generate classes on the fly, in memory. [Javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist) is probably easiest to start with since it permits using Java syntax.

They also tend to be lighter weight than entire standalone compilers.

Answer (score 0):

A (more) straightforward solution would be to do the following:

- Compile your class files into a common directory
- Create a custom `ClassLoader` that extends `ClassLoader`
- Use this `ClassLoader` to read in the .class files.

Here's something to get you started - I'll leave the exercise of getting the byte code into the object as an exercise to the reader.  (It isn't very difficult if you use a bit of `SimpleFileVisitor` work in this.  [Check out Java.NIO.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html))

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    @Override
    public Class findClass(String binaryClassName) {
        byte[] b = customLoadClassData(binaryClassName);
        return defineClass(binaryClassName, b, 0, b.length);
    }

    private byte[] customLoadClassData(String binaryClassName) {
        // Be sure to read in the specific .class file you want.
        // A tip is to handle this *outside* of this class.
    }

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
CustomClassLoader loader = new CustomClassLoader();
Class clazz = loader.findClass("com.stackoverflow.some.binary.name");
```

...provided that it didn't throw an exception or come back null.

Comment: thats what im doing the problem is that i dont want to create any physical files

Comment: ...but you did mention you were compiling the class somewhere, right?  It's not a huge problem if you have a ton of .class files; those can be safely removed after you're done...

Comment: i know it  just doesnt seem clean